# Ошибка: "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes ..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, графика, matplotlib

Код в файле test.py:

```
import main as tr

packetloss = tr.PacketLoss('iz.tr')
packetloss.plot()
```

А это часть маин:

```
def plot(self,*argv):
    #test sampling
    try:
        var=float(self.time_sample[3])
    except:
        var=-1
    if (var!=-1):

        try:
            _arg=list(argv)
            args=_arg[0]
        except:
            args='s-'
        plt.plot(self.time_sample,self.pdr_sample,args,label=self.legend)
    else:
        #plot array
        try:
            _arg=list(argv)
            args=_arg[0]
            plt.plot(self.time_array,self.pdr_array,args,label=self.legend)
        except :
            plt.plot(self.time_array,self.pdr_array,label=self.legend)
    plt.title('Packet Delivery Ratio [PDR]')
    plt.xlabel('Zaman [s]')
    plt.ylabel('PDR')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend()
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1)
    #plt.close()
```

В ответ получается это:

[image: Terminal]

Просто подскажите что я делаю не так. 
За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том что длины векторов переданных « plt.plot()» в качестве двух первых параметров должны совпадать

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, а как это исправить?

Comment: чтобы исправить надо передать `plt.plot()` списки координат __одинаковой длины__

Comment: @MaxU ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция `plt.plot(x, y, ...)` чертит точки, заданные `x` и `y` векторами / списками координат на плоскости.

Таким образом параметры `x` и `y` должны представлять из себя  списко-подобные объекты **одинаковой длины**.

Например:

```
from math import sin

def f(x):    
    return sin(x)

x = [ii/10 for ii in range(-100, 100)]
y = [f(ii) for ii in x]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Ответ:**

Ошибка сообщает вам о том, что `plt.plot()` не может начертить точки, если длины списков `X` координат и `Y` координат не совпадают.

Пример:

```
plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2])
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (2,)
```

**И на самом деле мы не можем начертить точку на двухмерной плоскости, если у этой точки присутствует только одна координата - `x`.**

Comment: Всё ясно спасибо!